# adding text inside a span based on turnary condition using razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
<span id="ContinueSpan">@{Model.SelectedTab == 5 ? "Submit": "Continue"} 
    <span aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;&nbsp;→</span>
</span>
```

The above code is throwing an exception. I am wondering what is wrong with it.

Comment: What exception? (and it would need to be `@( .. )` not `@{ .. }`)

Comment: `<span id="ContinueSpan">@(Model.SelectedTab == 5 ? "Submit" : "Continue")<span aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;&nbsp;→</span></span>`